# tomcat SSL error, http-bio-8080-exec-3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT: fatal, handshake_failure

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

We are trying to configure 2way SSL in tomcat on Ubuntu to make a call to remote server. However, it is keep failing at the same point.

The connector in tomcat7 is configured in this way:

```
  <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               keystoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat7/.keystore" keystorePass="XXX"
               truststoreFile="/usr/share/tomcat7/.truststore" truststorePass="XXX"
               clientAuth="false" sslEnabledProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
```

And we keystore has our certificate and trust store file has their root cert.

Could someone provide some insights about the SSL errors we are having? It seems that all the handshakes are complete but erros out at the last minute.

```
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Supported Signature Algorithms: SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x4, signature:0x2), SHA256withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x5, signature:0x2), SHA384withECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<Empty>
http-bio-8080-exec-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 4
*** ServerHelloDone
*** Certificate chain
***
*** ECDHClientKeyExchange
.. 
..
..
... no IV derived for this protocol
http-bio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 183, 168, 95, 241, 218, 172, 176, 12, 37, 224, 114, 81 }
***
http-bio-8080-exec-3, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 80
http-bio-8080-exec-3, READ: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
http-bio-8080-exec-3, RECV TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-18, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
http-bio-8080-exec-3, called closeSocket()
http-bio-8080-exec-3, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
http-bio-8080-exec-3, called close()
http-bio-8080-exec-3, called closeInternal(true)
15:48:20,800 INFO  [HTTPSender] Unable to sendViaPost to url[https://xxx]
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Trying to write END_DOCUMENT when document has no root (ie. trying to output empty document).
```

Another debug out from SSLDUMP

```
1 1  0.0266 (0.0266)  C>S  Handshake
      ClientHello
        Version 3.3 
        cipher suites
        Unknown value 0xc023
        Unknown value 0xc009
        Unknown value 0xc027
        Unknown value 0xc013
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_NULL_SHA
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x40
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0xc024
        Unknown value 0xc00a
        Unknown value 0xc028
        Unknown value 0xc014
        TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        Unknown value 0x6a
        TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
        compression methods
                  NULL
1 2  0.0532 (0.0266)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerHello
        Version 3.3 
        session_id[0]=

        cipherSuite         Unknown value 0xc027
        compressionMethod                   NULL
1 3  0.0771 (0.0238)  S>C  Handshake
      Certificate
1 4  0.0771 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      ServerKeyExchange
1 5  0.0771 (0.0000)  S>C  Handshake
      CertificateRequest
        certificate_types                   rsa_sign
        certificate_types                   dss_sign
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you connect if you don't use a client certificate? Just to make sure that the "normal" TLS handshake works before adding the client certificate into the mix. Does the client fail with handshake_failure, or does the server?

Comment: Yes. It can connect. Client fail with handshake_failure. Server is LB. Traffic is not reaching the application tier yet.

Comment: Did you install JCE (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html)? If you want to configure your system to work with AES_256 (part of `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA`), you'd need to have cryptographic extensions installed. JDK does not support AES-256 compatible keys by default.

Comment: The Connector is only used for connections from clients like browsers *to* Tomcat and has no effect on connections from code *in* Tomcat *to* somewhere else, which appears to be what you are asking about. **What code is doing the connection out?** HttpsUrlConnection? Apache httpclient? something else? Clearly it wasn't (correctly) given a keystore it could use for client auth aka client cert. And who on Earth configured it to offer DHE_DSS_WITH_NULL? If you ever encounter a server with a DSA cert (which is admittedly rare) that is NOT SECURE AT ALL!

Comment: @Ivan Only Oracle JRE requires JCE policy, openjdk doesn't; but if needed we know it is installed because otherwise JSSE would filter the AES256 suites from its offered list and it didn't.

Comment: Thanks for everyone who provided the answer. The issue is resolved by recreating the java keystore with full certificate and including the private key (which we missed). After that, SSL handshake finished properly.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Two-way SSL is just a confusing way to say that TLS client-certificates are in use to authenticate the client to the server during the TLS handshake. In this case, browser-to-server communication is the only thing in play.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz (1) Q says 'tomcat ... to make a call to a remote server'; since browser/client *always* goes to a server, saying 'remote' strongly suggests a second server (2) trace shows 'read' ServerHelloDone, and ClientKX followed by 'write' CCS and Finished; both of these are done by TLS client, but never TLS server (3) trace shows CertRequest with 'empty', but JSSE server never does that, and with unknown sigalgs, which it wouldn't do (4) Q shows `<Connector ... clientAuth="false" ...>` and JSSE server with ClientAuth unset doesn't send CertRequest at all.